# How to colour methods and functions in Qt Creator's text editor?

Tags: qt-creator, text-coloring

Visual Assist has a feature for [colouring](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/color.asp) methods and functions in VS's text editor.

Is it possible and how do I apply colour to method and function names in Qt Creator's text editor?

I have found only virtual methods colour in Qt Creator's settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the colour of method and function names by changing **Text** in Tools / Options / Text Editor / Color Scheme. In addition to method and function names **Text** determines the style of a few other things (for example macro names) as well, but I can live with it.

Comment: This seems to be a workaround. If somebody can suggest more accurate solution please add your answer. Meanwhile I will accept this answer.